# Batch - input username/pw when prompted

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cmd, putty, plink

I am new to using batch so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, BUT, the scenario is I have several switches that I need to manage using SSH. I am currently using plink(putty) to do so through the command prompt. I'm able to connect to my switches but I'm confused on how to automate the login portion.

What I'm trying to figure out is when I connect to the switch I am stopped 3 times and asked for input, one time for username, again for username(i dont know why its twice) and then finally for password. All of that before I can actually run commands on the switch.

So in my very archaic batch file I'm attempting to do the following.

```
echo
plink SESSIONNAME -l username -pw password
enable
config
crypto key generate rsa
```

the switch however doesn't want to cooperate with plink in accepting the input username and pw, instead prompting me to input that same information into cmdprompt. Is there a way in batch to have it "wait" for the switch to prompt me for the username and then input it, then "wait" for the switch to prompt me for the password and input that as well? All before executing my desired commands?

Every search I've done has only given me the results for the other way around, where the batch file would prompt the user for input, rather than whatever im connecting to prompting me for input.

Its possible I am just unaware of the proper terms to search for, if thats the case please let me know so I can redo my research. I'm just at a point where I'm not sure where to go or what to ask.

Plink log output

```
User Name:USERNAME

Password:PASSWORD


source#
```

Additional

```
Looking up host "X"
Connecting to X port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.4p1.RL
We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.66
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 XXXXXXX
Initialised AES-256 CBC client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 CBC server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "USERNAME".
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
```

Comment: Can you use `plink username@session -pw password` instead?

Comment: Show us the Plink output. And PuTTY event log for the same session, so that we can tell what kind of prompts these are.

Comment: @SomethingDark That's functionally identical to what the OP is already doing with `plink SESSIONNAME -l username -pw password`.

Comment: I had only ever seen the username@session syntax before. Good to know.

Comment: Sorry, something else took my attention for the rest of the day, when I get time I will update with the information.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl when I looked up how to get the PuTTY event log while using plink (in cmd prompt) it stated to use -v and output to a file, when I do that for WHATEVER reason the user and pw prompt no longer display in the window but only in the log. So I updated my original post to include what it stated. There was also some information displayed in the command prompt that didn't appear in the log that I've also included.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I've understood that you are prompted twice for the username/password. I do not see the second prompt anywhere in the output nor the log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl in this case since i connected using a session it put it into the field "Using username "USERNAME"." If I had used just the IP of the switch it would have asked for username, then username again then password.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might run into the same issue, I ended up needing to set up a linux box(ubuntu in my case) and then install expect, **sudo apt-get install expect**, then create a script working around that. The syntax is fairly simple, mine ended up similar to whats below. Links to useful resources I found are below that. To be more specific on the devices, they were Dell PowerConnect switches, ranging between series, 3400, 3500, and 6200.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

spawn /usr/bin/plink -ssh HOST

expect -exact "User Name:"

send "USERNAME\r"

expect -exact "Password:"

send "PASSWORD\r"

send "whatevercommandsyouwant\r"

send "exit\r"

expect eof
```

Its not perfect but it drastically reduces the amount of time spent updating switches or gathering config info.

[Debugging Expect](https://wiki.tcl.tk/3173)

[Expect Examples](https://www.pantz.org/software/expect/expect_examples_and_tips.html)